# I can't create tags on mobile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-creation, mobile-site

I request the "feature" of the mobile version of the site being able to create tags.

Comment: If your feature request is intended to be implemented across the entire network, I suggest you use [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/). You would get a larger audience, with a greater chance of something happening.

Answer (score 5):

You're not [the first person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109063/why-cant-i-create-a-new-tag-in-mobile) to want this functionality either for the mobile site or [the official apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/allow-creating-new-tags). Mind you, you can get around it by going to the full site on your phone as a workaround, or by using a different tag and leaving a comment asking for someone to add the proper tag.

[There is a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/allow-creating-new-tags) to add this functionality to the mobile site, but as you can see, nothing really has come of it, as there is a large concern around incorrect tags being created due to autocorrect and other situations where things can get typed incorrectly on mobile devices.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The mobile site design has been replaced with a [responsive version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/179041) which has all the features of the site when viewed in desktop mode, including the ability to create tags.

Comment: Um... https://i.stack.imgur.com/vifCj.jpg ? What was I doing wrong? I had to go to my chrome settings on my phone and enable the desktop site mode and then it let me create the tag.  I've been having other weird issues with copy and paste on my phone as well on our site.

Comment: @TimmyJim huh, that's really odd? I [tested it myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzxWP.png) and had no issue 

Comment: I feel like the responsive site stuff doesn't always work for me.